# System Architecture using Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am modeling a system (A) that notifies system (B) when something changes on system (C).

So my my system (A) just make pooling on system (C), using an API and when something changes then notifies system (B).

The system (C) stores status about an order. This status can be X, Y, Z.
It can take minutes to hours for the order to transition from state X to Y. And it can take days for the order to transition from Y to Z.

If I model my system just using one queue, I think I going to have some problems. 
I could have a moment that I will have much more message from state Y-->Z than state X-->Y because the Y-->Z has a update time greater than X-->Y. 
So it is going to take a long time to process X-->Y. To prevent this I think I have to clone the message and re-enqueue it, to put it back to end of the queue.

Instead of one queue, I can have two queues, one for each status.

I simplify the problem. In the original problem I can have multiple status. (I think it is 5 status).

Do you guys have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the queue separate for each status is best option for your use case as you don't have to worry or tune one queue for handling both the status.

Answer (score 0):

Queue system are not fail-safe. Queue parser must be able to handle application crash.

- If required, implement process to make sure queue are not processes twice. (program might read but failed to consumed the message after processing )
- Implement a failed safe house keeping process that republish works IF queue server went down and wipe all the message with it.
- Amazon SQS maximum message retention period are 14 days. Even for own MQ server, it is high risk to store "long term" message.
- Whether your X-->Y , or Y-->Z process that take different processing timeframe , it doesn't matter. If you publish message to queue ASAP when change is trigger(say Y--> Z changes happens after 24 days), then there should be no waiting issues. IMHO, I see no reason you raise question about "re-enqueue".